# React onLoad not calling function im passing in?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use the React onLoad function, but it's not calling. Check the code below and please suggest some solutions.

```
import { useRef } from 'react';

import './ProductCard.css';
 
export default function ProductCard(props) {

    const stars = useRef();

    function setStars() {
        for (let i = 0; i < props.product.priority; i++) { 
            stars.current.children[i].classList.add('checked');
        }
    }

    return(
        <div>
            <div className="card">
            <h1>{props.product.productName}</h1>
            <p className="price">${props.product.price}</p>
            <p ref={stars} className="importance" onLoad={setStars}>
                <span className="fa fa-star"></span>
                <span className="fa fa-star"></span>
                <span className="fa fa-star"></span>
                <span className="fa fa-star"></span>
                <span className="fa fa-star"></span>
            </p>
            <p><button onClick={() => window.open(props.product.productUrl)}>Visit site</button></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I tried adding brackets to call it but then I got an error, please refer the below attached image for better understanding.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coRod.png)

Comment: I suggest you look into useEffect if you want to run some logic on component mount.

Comment: Check this out https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html `onload` works with body/window and frames

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to have some dynamic classes. If this is the case you don't need the `onLoad` event. You could use `className={...}` to pass a dynamic string.

```
import './ProductCard.css';
 
export default function ProductCard(props) {
    const prio = props.product.priority;

    return(
        <div>
            <div className="card">
                <h1>{props.product.productName}</h1>
                <p className="price">${props.product.price}</p>
                <p className="importance">
                    {Array.from({ length: 5 }, (_, i) => (
                        <span
                            key={i}
                            className={`fa fa-star ${i < prio ? 'checked' : ''}`}
                        />
                    ))}
                </p>
                {/* this button should probably be a link that is styled like a button */}
                <p><button onClick={() => window.open(props.product.productUrl)}>Visit site</button></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

The above uses [template string interpolation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) (`` `1 + 1 = ${1 + 1}` //=> "1 + 1 = 2" ``) to evaluate an expression inside a string. And the [conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_operator) to add "checked" into the template string if the *index* is lower than the provided *priority*.

The above code uses [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to create an array of 5 `<span>` elements. Because I replaced the literal `<span>` elements with a loop we need to add `key`s to help React identify the elements. See [Why does React need keys?](https://react.dev/learn/rendering-lists#why-does-react-need-keys) It's not the best practice to use the index, but since that's the only unique thing about each `<span>`, so it's the only thing we can use.